# Not getting desired results with pandas pivot

Tags: pandas, tuples, pivot-table

I have a list of tuple which I'm trying to turn into a dataframe. 
The list looks like this:

```
data =
 ['Previous Close', '38.08'],
 ['Open', '38.23'],
 ['Bid', '37.67 x 100'],
 ['Ask', '38.16 x 500'],
 ["Day's Range", '37.35 - 38.25'],
 ['52 Week Range', '23.50 - 40.92']
```

I want the left portion of each tuple to represent the column and the right to represent the values. In this case, **there would only be one row as the index because we would have only one row of data**

ATM, I'm not really concerned with the labeling of the index (though, I prefer it to be'AA')

My attempt at getting the desire results were:
First create a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which produced:

```
     0               1
0   Previous Close  38.08
1   Open            38.23
2   Bid             37.67 x 100
3   Ask             38.16 x 500
4   Day's Range     37.35 - 38.25
```

I then attempted to use pivot to get the values from column 0 as my column names and the values from column 1 as my values for column one. It worked to a degree:

```
df.pivot( columns = 0, values =1)
```

But I have too many rows.

```
    1y Target Est   52 Week Range   Ask     Avg. Volume     ..............
0   None    None    None    None    None    None    None        None    None    

1   None    None    None    None    None    None    None        None    None 

2   None    None    None    None    None    None    None        None    None 

3

4   $58
```

I want only one row, since there is only one row of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup***

```
data = [
    ['Previous Close', '38.08'],
    ['Open', '38.23'],
    ['Bid', '37.67 x 100'],
    ['Ask', '38.16 x 500'],
    ["Day's Range", '37.35 - 38.25'],
    ['52 Week Range', '23.50 - 40.92']
]
```

***Option 1***

```
pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(0).T

0 Previous Close   Open          Bid          Ask    Day's Range  52 Week Range
1          38.08  38.23  37.67 x 100  38.16 x 500  37.35 - 38.25  23.50 - 40.92
```

***Option 2***

```
c, v = list(zip(*data))
pd.DataFrame([v], columns=c)

  Previous Close   Open          Bid          Ask    Day's Range  52 Week Range
0          38.08  38.23  37.67 x 100  38.16 x 500  37.35 - 38.25  23.50 - 40.92
```

***Option 3***
*Python 3 unpacking*
*This will work for greater number of rows*

```
c, *v = list(zip(*data))
pd.DataFrame(v, columns=c)

  Previous Close   Open          Bid          Ask    Day's Range  52 Week Range
0          38.08  38.23  37.67 x 100  38.16 x 500  37.35 - 38.25  23.50 - 40.92
```

Comment: Thanks =). I will use the first one, but the others are a great reference tool -- Going to bookmark. 

Just for clarification, set_index (0) is labeling the the first row of the index as  0 right?

Comment: The way you have `data` laid out relative to how you want your dataframe, the things you want as column headers are the first elements of each row.  Also, when I call `pd.DataFrame` on `data`, I don't specify `columns` and so I get the default.  That means the first elements get the first column position.  So `df.set_index(0)` takes the first column and turns that into the index.  Then I transpose with `.T`

Comment: Ah,  I see. Thank you~